# Excel advanced filter dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data connection to an internal website that grabs a full webpage and imports it to the "DC" sheet. From there it's moved to "staging" via an advanced filter macro using the below code. The N1100 is not the last row with text, it was a arbitrary number a fair distance past the end of my data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Password_Unprotect

    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DC")
    Dim lrng As Range
       Set lrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DC").Range("A158:N1100")
    Dim crng As Range
        Set crng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DC").Range("A158:N1100")

    Dim copyto As Range
        Set copyto = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Staging").Range("A1:H1")

    lrng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, crng, copyto, Unique:=False

    'Call password_protect  
End Sub
```

My problem is that whenever the the webpage I use for my data connection changes it breaks my advanced filter since the row my criteria starts on shifts. I'm looking to either make the advanced filter smart enough to find the line it needs to start on or delete every line above it then move the data over to the "staging" sheet. A point of note, the cell containing "Division" is unique on the sheet. The highlighted line is the start of the advanced filter.

I've uploaded a snit-it of my worksheet.
[image: I've uploaded a snip-it of my worksheet.]

Comment: a combination of OFFSET & MATCH should be able to help you determine a start point, or use a dynamic named range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should get you what you looking for. Just need to run through `Column A` to look for the DEVICE text and then use that as start and then do a `.End(xlUp)` on `Column A` for the last Row.

Another note, always remember to use `Option Explicit` on on all your sheet to ensure you always declaring your variables.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call Password_Unprotect

    Dim DCSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lrng As Range
    Dim crng As Range
    Dim copyto As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim ColACell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set DCSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DC")

    LastRow = DCSheet.Cells(DCSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Stopping at 300 will just save time if the text is not found
    'if it is possible that the start row could be further down then increase the number
    For Each ColACell In DCSheet.Range("A1:A300").Cells
        If ColACell.Text = "DEVICE" Then
            'Can have cross check for the IP text in Column B
            If ColACell.Offset(0, 1).Text = "IP" Then StartRow = ColACell.Row
        End If
    Next ColACell

    Set lrng = DCSheet.Range("A" & StartRow & ":N" & LastRow)
    Set crng = DCSheet.Range("A" & StartRow & ":N" & LastRow)
    Set copyto = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Staging").Range("A1:H1")

    lrng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, crng, copyto, Unique:=False

    'Call password_protect

End Sub
```